# Qt6 и новый синтаксис сигналов и слотов

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу разобраться в том, как использовать новый синтаксис сигналов и слотов в Qt5 на основе указателей на методы. Из книги я взял такой код:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QSpinBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget* window = new QWidget;
    window->setWindowTitle("Set your age");

    QSpinBox* spinBox = new QSpinBox;
    QSlider* slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
    spinBox->setRange(0, 130);
    slider->setRange(0, 130);

    QObject::connect(spinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, slider, &QSlider::setValue);
    QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spinBox, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    spinBox->setValue(35);

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(spinBox);
    layout->addWidget(slider);
    window->setLayout(layout);

    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

И немного поправил строку, чтобы вместо макросов использовались указатели на методы:

```
QObject::connect(spinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, slider, &QSlider::setValue);
```

После этого код перестал компилироваться, выдается ошибка

> error: no matching function for call to
> 'QObject::connect(QSpinBox*&, <unresolved overloaded function
> type>, QSlider*&, void (QAbstractSlider::*)(int))'    17 |
> QObject::connect(spinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, slider,
> &QSlider::setValue);
> |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Как правильно использовать сигналы и слоты с новым синтаксисом, чтобы такая ошибка не возникала?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема возникает потому, что в вызове `connect` нет однозначности какую перегрузку `valueChanged` использовать. А в классе `QSpinBox` их две:

```
void valueChanged(int);
void valueChanged(const QString &);
```

В [справке об этом сигнале](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged), кстати, как раз указано про способ разрешения этой проблемы:

> Note: Signal valueChanged is overloaded in this class. To connect to this signal by using the function pointer syntax, Qt provides a convenient helper for obtaining the function pointer as shown in this example:
>
> ```
> connect(spinBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
>    [=](int i){ /* ... */ });
> ```

Чуть лаконичнее это делается с помощью хелпер шаблона [qOverload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qoverload-qtcore-proxy.html#qOverload):

```
connect(spinBox, qOverload<int>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
    [=](int i){ /* ... */ });
```

А вот в Qt6 (который упомянут в заголовке вопроса) подобной проблемы похоже бы не возникло, т.к. они [убрали](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qspinbox.html#valueChanged) перегрузку со строкой и она теперь имеет [самостоятельное название](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qspinbox.html#textChanged):

```
void QSpinBox::textChanged(const QString &text)
```